# What is the difference between this sign-and-encrypt code and encrypt and sign a file sequentially?

Tags: c#, .net, bouncycastle, pgp

This [page](http://www.bouncycastle.org/devmailarchive/msg08137.html) has a code snippet for signing and encrypting a file in one step (under SIGNING AND ENCRYPTING CODE).

What is the difference between this and sequentially encrypting and then signing the file (using `KeyBasedFileProcessor` and `SignedFileProcessor` of Bouncy Castle Crypto respectively)?

Answer (score 1):

See [this article](http://world.std.com/~dtd/sign_encrypt/sign_encrypt7.html).

> Why is naïve Sign & Encrypt insecure? Most simply, S&E is vulnerable to ``surreptitious forwarding:'' Alice signs & encrypts for Bob's eyes, but Bob re-encrypts Alice's signed message for Charlie to see. In the end, Charlie believes Alice wrote to him directly, and can't detect Bob's subterfuge. Bob might do this just to embarass Alice, or Charlie, or both
>
> ...
>
> Interestingly, naïve Encrypt-then-Sign isn't any better than Sign & Encrypt. In this case, it's easy for any eavesdropper to replace the sender's signature with his own, so as to claim authorship for the encrypted plaintext

Comment: Did you check the article? The two paragraphs I provided are about sequential operations (sign-then-encrypt and encrypt-then-sign). They are to certain extent "flawed". SignAndEncrypt as one operation, as performed in CMS and OpenPGP, is one operation and it doesn't (supposedly) have shortcomings discussed in the article for sequential operations.